# How do I do a FAST conversion of an int array to an array of bytes?

Tags: go, type-conversion, memcpy

I have a process that needs to pack a large array of `int16`s to a protobuf every few milliseconds. Understanding the protobuf side of it isn't critical, since all I really need is a way to convert a bunch of `int16`s (160-16k of them) to `[]byte`. It's a CPU-critical operation, so I don't want to do something like this:

```
for _, sample := range listOfIntegers {
  protobufObject.ByteStream = append(protobufObject.Bytestream, byte(sample>>8))
  protobufObject.ByteStream = append(protobufObject.Bytestream, byte(sample&0xff))
}
```

(If you're interested, this is the protobuf)

```
message ProtobufObject {
  bytes byte_stream = 1;
  ...               = 2;
  etc.
}
```

There has to be a faster way to supply that list of ints as a block of memory to the protobuf. I've fiddled with the cgo library to get access to memcpy, but suspect I've been destroying an underlying go data structure because I get crashes in totally unrelated sections of code.

Comment: It should be faster if you pre-allocate `ByteStream` (with `make`) and index into it to set values instead of using `append`. I'm not sure if you need more optimization than that, though.

Comment: The right-shift and bitwise & aren't free. The fact that this is taking a long block of memory and replicating it, verbatim, somewhere else - burning CPU time to deal with go's over-mothering type enforcement is ridiculous. I could accept a memcpy - grudgingly - since I have to work with the garbage collector (the source allocation might be reaped before the destination, so maybe I can't just reference the same block of memory without updating the reference count,) but this is just too much.

Comment: You can use the `unsafe` package to get a pointer to the data in your list and create a byte slice that points to the same memory. (I assume you're aware that the values you're putting in that byte slice are in big-endian order, so you're not ending up with the same string of bytes that's in the original list if you're on a little-endian machine.)

Answer (score 1):

A faster version of the above code is:

```
protobufObject.ByteStream := make([]byte, len(listOfIntegers) * 2)
for i, n := range listOfIntegers {
  j := i * 2
  protobufObject.ByteStream[j+1] = byte(n)
  protobufObject.ByteStream[j] = byte(n>>8)
}
```

You can avoid copying the data when running on a big-endian architecture.

Use the [unsafe](https://godoc.org/unsafe#Pointer) package to copy the `[]int16` header to the `[]byte` header.  Use the unsafe package again to get a pointer to the `[]byte` [header](https://godoc.org/reflect#SliceHeader) and adjust the length and capacity for the conversion.

```
b = *(*[]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&listOfIntegers))
hdr := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
hdr.Len *= 2
hdr.Cap *= 2
protobufObject.ByteStream = b
```